# using linq with Join and Max using DataTables

Tags: c#, linq, join, datatable, max

Excuse my Newby attempt but I have spent a week on this one silly problem and am determined to use LINQ

This is my SQL Query - Generated with SQL Query builder

```
    SELECT TABLE1.ID, MAX(DISTINCT TABLE2.TEXT) AS Expr1

    FROM TABLE1 

    INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.PARENT_ID

    GROUP BY TABLE1.ID
```

I want to  display Table1 rows and the last table2 row eg
    ID    TEXT
    1     'final comment for record 1'
    2     'final comment for record 2'

Using C# I have two DataTables

```
DataTable DT_Nodes = sess_nodes.ds.Tables["TABLE1"];
DataTable DT_Sticky = sess_nodes.ds.Tables["TABLE2"];

var linq_test = from tab1 in DT_Nodes.AsEnumerable()
join tab2 in DT_Sticky.AsEnumerable()
on tab1["ID"] equals tab2["PARENT_ID"]
group tab1 by tab1.Field<long>("ID") into result
select <I am stuck here>;
```

I want to display result, using a loop

```
foreach(DataRow resultrow in linq_test)
{
<stuck here also>
long id = resultrow.table1["ID"];     // This needs to be the ID in table1
long id_tab2 = resultrow.table2["ID"] // This needs to be the last if the ID's of table2
}
```

I have tried various ways however the linq syntax has beaten me and most samples on the web aren't using DataTables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that the Good Lord gave us LINQ, so they we could *stop* using DataTables....

```
DataTable DT_Nodes = sess_nodes.ds.Tables["TABLE1"];
DataTable DT_Sticky = sess_nodes.ds.Tables["TABLE2"];

var linq_test = from tab1 in DT_Nodes.AsEnumerable()
    join tab2 in DT_Sticky.AsEnumerable()
            on tab1["ID"] equals tab2["PARENT_ID"]
    group new {Table1=tab1, Text=tab2["TEXT"]}
     by tab1.Field<long>("ID") into result
    select new {
             Id = result.Key,
             Text = result.Last().Text
             };
```

If the only thing we need from Table1 is the ID, then we can simplify this a bit:

```
var linq_test = from tab1 in DT_Nodes.AsEnumerable()
    join tab2 in DT_Sticky.AsEnumerable()
            on tab1["ID"] equals tab2["PARENT_ID"]
    group tab2["TEXT"] by tab1.Field<long>("ID") into result
    select new {
                 Id = result.Key,
                 Text = result.Last()
               }
```

Comment: James, many thanks. The line "Text = result.Last().select(l=>l.Text) doesn't compile. When I removed the .select(l=l.Text) it does but returns no results.